# Disable Eclipse build while updating with Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, build, subclipse

When I update my working copy, Eclipse launches a build (Maven build).

The problem is, for big updates (or merges), the build significantly slow down the process because it tries to build after each file updated.

Is there a way to disable this behavior, and have it build at the end of the update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might already know this but in the Project menu you can disable the automatic builds.  Might be a few extra clicks but could save some time.  I don't know any other way to do it after *all* the updates.

[image]

Comment: Yes I know that, I'm not enough desperate for that right now :p, but I might use that if no solution comes up...

Comment: what about creating a macro that disables auto build, updates the projects and turns it back on?  No idea what the best macro tool for eclipse is but sounds like there are some available.